# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined ReactJS I am new

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new at this
when moving a card to another card in the same list it is done without any problem but when moving a card to a different list I get this error
[image]

```
 return (
  <ContextApi.Provider value={{ updateBoardTitle, addBoard, addCard }}>
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId="1234" type="board" direction="horizontal">
          {(provided) => (
            <div
              className={classes.container}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.droppableProps}
            >
              {data.listIds.map((listID) => {
                const list = data.lists[listID];
                return <Board list={list} key={listID} />;
              })}
              <div>
                <BoardAdd type="board" />
                {provided.placeholder}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
    </div>
  </ContextApi.Provider>
);
```

Data comes from an array called mockData.js and here he declared it

```
    function App() {
  const classes = useStyle();
  const [data, setData] = useState(mockData);
  console.log(data);
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

here is the mockData code

```
    import uuid from "react-uuid";

const mockData = {
  lists: {
    "01list": {
      id: "01list",
      title: "Orders",
      card: [
        {
          id: "01card",
          title: "Churraco",
          table: "6",
          amount: "1",
        },
        {
          id: "02card",
          title: "Sopa de Almejas",
          table: "14",
          amount: "1",
        },
        {
          id: uuid(),
          title: "",
          table: "",
          amount: "",
        },
      ],
    },
    "02list": {
      id: "02list",
      title: "In Progress",
      card: [],
    },
    "03list": {
      id: "03list",
      title: "Finish",
      card: [
        {
          id: uuid(),
          title: "Parillada",
          table: "9",
          amount: "1",
        },
        {
          id: uuid(),
          title: "Parillada",
          table: "9",
          amount: "1",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  listIds: ["01list", "02list", "03list"],
};

export default mockData;
```

I don't think I'm good for programming :(

Comment: Do you export mockdata? And can you show `listIds`?

Comment: Where is `listIds` in `mockData`?